# Spring -> convert cassandra column data value from long to Date using Spring Converter

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra, converters

My problem is as follows

1. I have a BigInt column in a cassandra table
2. In the corresponding POJO I have a Date field
3. When I insert data into the cassandra table using Spring Cassandra Repository the Date automatically gets converted to Long
4. When I try selecting the row from the table , I get an error while Spring tries to map the value of Long to a Date

Although I have implemented a custom converter

```
public class LongToDateConverter implements Converter<Long,Date> {

        public Date convert(final Long source) {

            if(null!= source)
            {
                return new Date(source);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }    
}
```

and registered it in spring config

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
    <context:annotation-config />    
    <bean id="conversionService"                    class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
     <property name="converters">
<list>
<bean class="com.app.converter.LongToDateConverter" />
</list>
</property>
```

and i also have a cassandra config

```
<cassandra:cluster contact-points="localhost" port="9042" />
<cassandra:session keyspace-name="xxxx" />
<cassandra:mapping />
<cassandra:converter />
<cassandra:template id="cassandraTemplate" />
```

But I still get an exception

The exception is as follows

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.Long to type java.util.Date
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:276)
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:171)
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:153)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.getPotentiallyConvertedValue(BeanWrapper.java:157)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.setProperty(BeanWrapper.java:75)
    org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readPropertyFromRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:187)
    org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:150)
    org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:145)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:307)
    org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readPropertiesFromRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:145)
    org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readEntityFromRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:137)
    org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:114)
    org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.read(MappingCassandraConverter.java:202)
    org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraConverterRowCallback.doWith(CassandraConverterRowCallback.java:47)
    org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.selectOne(CassandraTemplate.java:491)
    org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.selectOne(CassandraTemplate.java:365)
    org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.selectOneById(CassandraTemplate.java:286)
    org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.findOne(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:69)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:405)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:390)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    $Proxy17.findOne(Unknown Source)
    com.app.services.UserProfileService.get(UserProfileService.java:21)
    com.social.facebook.PostFaceBookSocialLogin.initiate(PostFaceBookSocialLogin.java:87)
    com.social.facebook.FacebookController.facebookAccess(FacebookController.java:87)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:98)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:102)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:82)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
```

Comment: What is your import in  `LongToDateConverter` ? Is it `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?